# VSCode import "C" fails on modules

Tags: c, go, visual-studio-code, cgo

Please see the following screenshot:

[image: vscode with golang import "C" error]

It says:

> could not import C (no package data for import path C)

I have attached an example project that reproduces the failure, here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/files/3783446/example-project.zip

I am using Go 1.13 with the latest versions of each extension for Go and C/C++.
There is no compiler error, and this is specifically seemingly isolated as a "vscode problem".

Is there a way to fix this vscode problem?

Comment: Is this a compile error or just the IDE not knowing about CGo?

Comment: @gonutz there is no compile error, i will clarify the question with that detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in `gopls` tool distributed in the official golang packages.

Here are the issue links:

- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32898
- https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/tools/+/202238/

---

info from issue report:

```
internal/lsp: use Go/cgo source files instead of generated files

Using CompiledGoFiles was causing metadata lookups to fail for cgo
packages because it includes generated files in the Go build cache
when the built-in 'go list' driver is used.  GoFiles includes both
Go and cgo original file names, allowing metadata lookups to
succeed.
```

---

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the extra new line between the import, you can try with the following:

```golang
// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
// #include <stdio.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <string.h>
// #include "cutils.h"
import "C"
import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
// ...
)
```

[image: CGO import example]
Have a look here for other example related to CGO:
https://github.com/alessiosavi/GoUtils/blob/master/GoUtils.go

Comment: except for I only have 1 import that that is `import "C"`

Comment: oddly enough, I added an empty import right below that, as you suggest, and now I got intellisense. gmft has removed the empty import immediatly but issue is fixe. So thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug with VSCode and I've written a medium article for this issue.

https://medium.com/@mourya.g9/setting-up-confluent-kafka-client-for-golang-with-vscode-7a27bb94220b. Hope this helps.

Comment: i have filed an issue on the vscode github repository